Why is the pgvector index not being used?
I have the following query using PostgreSQL and pgvector
I've created an index on the vector column
CREATE INDEX ON news_items_embedding USING hnsw (embedding_open_ai_large halfvec_cosine_ops)

The query is
SELECT embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,0.0135269165,...]' AS distance, news_items.id
FROM news_items inner join news_items_embedding on news_items_embedding.id = news_items.id
where news_items.publish_time >= '2024-02-12T23:01:00.000Z'
and news_items.publish_time < '2024-02-26T23:01:00.000Z'
and news_items.verified_state >= 1
and embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,0.0135269165,...]' < 0.2
order by embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,0.0135269165,...]'
limit 100

If I remove the line and news_items.publish_time < '2024-02-26T23:01:00.000Z' then the index on the vector column is used, but with that line in there it does a table scan on the vector column instead taking 30x longer.
Why is a table scan being used with that line in place? How can I force/encourage the use of the index by restructuring the query.
Below is the plan excluding and news_items.publish_time < '2024-02-26T23:01:00.000Z'
"Limit  (cost=320.89..698.43 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=1.031..1.259 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Output: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"  Buffers: shared hit=838"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=320.89..5074.20 rows=1259 width=40) (actual time=1.030..1.258 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Output: (news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"        Inner Unique: true"
"        Buffers: shared hit=838"
"        ->  Index Scan using news_items_embedding_embedding_open_ai_large_idx on public.news_items_embedding  (cost=320.60..748.90 rows=3207 width=22) (actual time=1.020..1.245 rows=2 loops=1)"
"              Output: news_items_embedding.id, news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large"
"              Order By: (news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)"
"              Filter: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec) < '0.19999999999999996'::double precision)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 38"
"              Buffers: shared hit=829"
"        ->  Index Scan using news_items_pkey on public.news_items  (cost=0.29..1.35 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=2)"
"              Output: news_items.id, news_items.url, news_items.s3_image_path, news_items.s3_image_format, news_items.s3_image_width, news_items.s3_image_height, news_items.publish_time, news_items.verified_time, news_items.ai_title, news_items.ai_summary_short, news_items.verified_state, news_items.tag_time, news_items.sentiment, news_items.last_click_time, news_items.newsletter_referrals, news_items.website_referrals, news_items.popularity, news_items.source_name, news_items.tags, news_items.region_tags, news_items.reject_tags, news_items.news_industries, news_items.business_categories"
"              Index Cond: (news_items.id = news_items_embedding.id)"
"              Filter: ((news_items.publish_time >= '2024-02-12 23:01:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (news_items.verified_state >= 1))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"              Buffers: shared hit=6"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=15"
"Planning Time: 0.187 ms"
"Execution Time: 1.279 ms"

Below in the plan including and news_items.publish_time < '2024-02-26T23:01:00.000Z'
"Limit  (cost=726.45..726.70 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=35.176..35.182 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Output: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"  Buffers: shared hit=30663"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=726.45..726.70 rows=103 width=40) (actual time=35.175..35.181 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Output: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"        Sort Key: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec))"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=30663"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=499.03..723.00 rows=103 width=40) (actual time=34.885..35.175 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              Output: (news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"              Inner Unique: true"
"              Hash Cond: (news_items_embedding.id = news_items.id)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=30663"
"              ->  Seq Scan on public.news_items_embedding  (cost=0.00..215.30 rows=3207 width=22) (actual time=6.648..34.778 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                    Output: news_items_embedding.id, news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large"
"                    Filter: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec) < '0.19999999999999996'::double precision)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 9618"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=29981"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=495.14..495.14 rows=311 width=32) (actual time=0.375..0.377 rows=408 loops=1)"
"                    Output: news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 35kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=679"
"                    ->  Index Scan using news_items_publish_time_index on public.news_items  (cost=0.29..495.14 rows=311 width=32) (actual time=0.007..0.336 rows=408 loops=1)"
"                          Output: news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"                          Index Cond: ((news_items.publish_time >= '2024-02-12 23:01:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (news_items.publish_time < '2024-02-26 23:01:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))"
"                          Filter: (news_items.verified_state >= 1)"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 279"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=679"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=15"
"Planning Time: 0.179 ms"
"Execution Time: 35.205 ms"

Below is the plan with SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = OFF;
"Limit  (cost=994.47..994.72 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=2.256..2.258 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Output: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"  Buffers: shared hit=3253"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=994.47..994.73 rows=103 width=40) (actual time=2.256..2.257 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Output: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"        Sort Key: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec))"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=3253"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..991.03 rows=103 width=40) (actual time=1.200..2.252 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              Output: (news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"              Inner Unique: true"
"              Buffers: shared hit=3253"
"              ->  Index Scan using news_items_publish_time_index on public.news_items  (cost=0.29..495.14 rows=311 width=32) (actual time=0.010..0.379 rows=408 loops=1)"
"                    Output: news_items.id, news_items.url, news_items.s3_image_path, news_items.s3_image_format, news_items.s3_image_width, news_items.s3_image_height, news_items.publish_time, news_items.verified_time, news_items.ai_title, news_items.ai_summary_short, news_items.verified_state, news_items.tag_time, news_items.sentiment, news_items.last_click_time, news_items.newsletter_referrals, news_items.website_referrals, news_items.popularity, news_items.source_name, news_items.tags, news_items.region_tags, news_items.reject_tags, news_items.news_industries, news_items.business_categories"
"                    Index Cond: ((news_items.publish_time >= '2024-02-12 23:01:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (news_items.publish_time < '2024-02-26 23:01:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))"
"                    Filter: (news_items.verified_state >= 1)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 279"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=679"
"              ->  Index Scan using news_items_embedding_pkey on public.news_items_embedding  (cost=0.29..1.59 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=408)"
"                    Output: news_items_embedding.id, news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large"
"                    Index Cond: (news_items_embedding.id = news_items.id)"
"                    Filter: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec) < '0.19999999999999996'::double precision)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2571"
"Settings: enable_seqscan = 'off'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=15"
"Planning Time: 0.179 ms"
"Execution Time: 2.278 ms"

After setting random_page_cost = '1.1'.
Query with where...
"Limit  (cost=595.70..595.95 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=2.701..2.702 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Output: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"  Buffers: shared hit=3267"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=595.70..595.95 rows=103 width=40) (actual time=2.700..2.701 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Output: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"        Sort Key: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec))"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=3267"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..592.25 rows=103 width=40) (actual time=1.493..2.695 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              Output: (news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"              Inner Unique: true"
"              Buffers: shared hit=3267"
"              ->  Index Scan using news_items_publish_time_index on public.news_items  (cost=0.29..375.67 rows=310 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.484 rows=408 loops=1)"
"                    Output: news_items.id, news_items.url, news_items.s3_image_path, news_items.s3_image_format, news_items.s3_image_width, news_items.s3_image_height, news_items.publish_time, news_items.verified_time, news_items.ai_title, news_items.ai_summary_short, news_items.verified_state, news_items.tag_time, news_items.sentiment, news_items.last_click_time, news_items.newsletter_referrals, news_items.website_referrals, news_items.popularity, news_items.source_name, news_items.tags, news_items.region_tags, news_items.reject_tags, news_items.news_industries, news_items.business_categories"
"                    Index Cond: ((news_items.publish_time >= '2024-02-12 23:01:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (news_items.publish_time < '2024-02-26 23:01:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))"
"                    Filter: (news_items.verified_state >= 1)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 279"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=700"
"              ->  Index Scan using news_items_embedding_pkey on public.news_items_embedding  (cost=0.29..0.70 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=408)"
"                    Output: news_items_embedding.id, news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large"
"                    Index Cond: (news_items_embedding.id = news_items.id)"
"                    Filter: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec) < '0.19999999999999996'::double precision)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2564"
"Settings: random_page_cost = '1.1'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=16"
"Planning Time: 0.209 ms"
"Execution Time: 2.725 ms"

Query without where...
"Limit  (cost=89.98..274.19 rows=100 width=40) (actual time=0.923..1.135 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Output: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"  Buffers: shared hit=825"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=89.98..2409.10 rows=1259 width=40) (actual time=0.922..1.133 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Output: (news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec), news_items.id, news_items.verified_state, news_items.source_name, news_items.publish_time"
"        Inner Unique: true"
"        Buffers: shared hit=825"
"        ->  Index Scan using news_items_embedding_embedding_open_ai_large_idx on public.news_items_embedding  (cost=89.70..312.10 rows=3207 width=22) (actual time=0.900..1.107 rows=2 loops=1)"
"              Output: news_items_embedding.id, news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large"
"              Order By: (news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec)"
"              Filter: ((news_items_embedding.embedding_open_ai_large <=> '[-0.048431396,...]'::halfvec) < '0.19999999999999996'::double precision)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 38"
"              Buffers: shared hit=816"
"        ->  Index Scan using news_items_pkey on public.news_items  (cost=0.29..0.65 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=2)"
"              Output: news_items.id, news_items.url, news_items.s3_image_path, news_items.s3_image_format, news_items.s3_image_width, news_items.s3_image_height, news_items.publish_time, news_items.verified_time, news_items.ai_title, news_items.ai_summary_short, news_items.verified_state, news_items.tag_time, news_items.sentiment, news_items.last_click_time, news_items.newsletter_referrals, news_items.website_referrals, news_items.popularity, news_items.source_name, news_items.tags, news_items.region_tags, news_items.reject_tags, news_items.news_industries, news_items.business_categories"
"              Index Cond: (news_items.id = news_items_embedding.id)"
"              Filter: ((news_items.publish_time >= '2024-02-12 23:01:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (news_items.verified_state >= 1))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"              Buffers: shared hit=6"
"Settings: random_page_cost = '1.1'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=16"
"Planning Time: 0.222 ms"
"Execution Time: 1.158 ms"


You could try (on a query by query basis only) SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = OFF;?

Could you please share the result from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this SQL statement? And all DDL for the tables and indexes involved. All in plain text please

@Vérace SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN = OFF; Does speed it up, but it's still not using news_items_embedding_embedding_open_ai_large_idx. I've added the analysis to the question

@FrankHeikens I've added the query analysis. Thanks for looking at this.

What is your configuration for random_page_costs ? And what about the rest of the configuration? Or is everything default?

@FrankHeikens Everything is default. I'm new to Postgres working on a migration from MongoDb.

Start with ALTER SYSTEM SET random_page_cost TO 1.1; SELECT pg_reload_conf(); to try a much lower setting to favor index scans.

A default configuration gives you a functional database that works on any platform, but not a high performance database for your application and platform.

Adjusting the random_page_cost results in much faster execution, giving me the same results as turning off ENABLE_SEQSCAN, but it's still not using news_items_embedding_embedding_open_ai_large_idx

Could you please update the query plans? And did you check the other configuration settings?

How many records in your two tables?

@FrankHeikens I've appended the query plans post random_page_cost change. I'm not sure what other configuration options to look at - I've got a lot of reading to do.

@Vérace I'm testing with 9620 rows in both tables. It's a 1:1 relationship just for logical separation of data.

news_items_embedding_embedding_open_ai_large_idx is used in both query plans when random_page_cost is set to 1.1 Looks like you're good for now, especially since both queries take about 1 millisecond to execute. You're not going to make this query much faster no matter what you do. However, you might want to test with more data.

@FrankHeikens My apologies, I pasted in the wrong query plan. I've now corrected it in the question. I'm assuming that leaving the random_page_cost at 1.1 is fine in a world of SSDs and the default is a legacy value for magnetic disks?

Yes, for now 1.1 is good enough. When using SSD you want something between 1.0 and 1.5 when seq_page_cost is set to 1.0 What is best for your application and database, depends on your usage pattern. That's something you have to test and validate.

Has changing random_page_cost made the query use your indexes? 9620 rows is nothing short of tiny - only a few pages per table - it's perhaps to be expected that your index isn't used? You should maybe try pgtune for other settings? As mentioned, the default settings (overall) are probably for machines which have long since ended up in landfill! :-) Don't forget that PostgreSQL is built for many different architectures (e.g. Raspberry Pi or 32 bit machines...). I wish they focused more on real servers (*nix, Windows...)!

How much RAM do you have and what is your setting of shared_buffers?

@Vérace I've set shared_buffers to 256MB. I've also discovered that if I drop the limit to 20 it will use the index with the full where clause. Any more than that and it stops using the index.

How much RAM do you have? Normally, it should be ~ 25% of RAM. Maybe dropping it to 20 (really small) makes the server say "we'd better stop using RAM here..."? Did you look at pgtune? It's not a panacea, but it might be of some help.

@Vérace This will soon be running on a min spec AWS instance with 1GB of RAM, which is why I set it to 256MB. I just tried setting shared_buffers to 1GB on my machine and it didn't change the query plan.

Lowering cpu_operator_cost might help, it does favor the index on the WHERE condition over the index on the ORDER BY. But you have to check the other queries on your database as well.
